# html not using servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm running through the java brains tutorials for jsp. I'm at the end of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnUJl3NYRRc&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96&index=6

My current issue is when I run my html submit form page I get my submit box with the url
`http://localhost:50373/DemoJSP/web/SimpleForm.html`

When entering in information and clicking submit it wont redirect to my servlet page. I get a 404 Not Found instead with this url
`http://localhost:50373/DemoJSP/web/xmlServletpath?userName=testinfo`

If I put in a url of `http://localhost/xmlServletpath?userName=testinfo` I'm able to hit the servlet code with an output of Hello!testinfo.

Im running tomcat on Intellij.

XmlServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(name = "XmlServlet")
public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        out.println("Hello!" + userName);

    }
}
```

SimpleForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="xmlServletpath">
    <input name="userName"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!--<welcome-file-list>-->
        <!--<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>-->
    <!--</welcome-file-list>-->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.nathan.javabrains.XmlServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>xmlServletpath</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

project structure

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<form action="xmlServletpath">
```

to

```
<form action="/xmlServletpath">
```

as with `/` is relative to the website root while without it is relative to the current URL.

Comment: I have tried with and without the / the results are the same.

Comment: Based on your Intellij project structure, the valid URL should be `http://localhost:50373/SimpleForm.html` and `http://localhost:50373/xmlServletpath?userName=testinfo` assuming tomcat has been changed to use port 50373. Also since the code is already using `@WebServlet`, better just use `@WebServlet(name="XmlServlet", urlPatterns="/xmlServletpath")` and remove both `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` from web.xml to avoid being unintentionally overridden.

Comment: That worked!!! The only question was I still don't understand why I couldn't get the xml file to work. I see this xml configuration often and wanted to be able to understand the issue. Either way thank you for your help.

Comment: `@WebServlet` is only introduced starting with Servlet version 3.0 as alternative to the xml confguration.  Xml configuration is still supported, you could remove the `@WebServlet` annotation and add the `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` back to `web.xml` and the program should work the same. Generally it is not a good idea to mix the two for the same servlet.

Comment: When I remove the @WebServlet annotaion and add back the servlet and servlet-mapping the same error comes back.  URL http://localhost:50797/xmlServletpath?userName=ljk 404 not found but if I type in http://localhost/xmlServletpath?userName=ljk it then works. Thank again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml` the URL pattern of your servlet must start with a slash:

```
<url-pattern>/xmlServletpath</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Combinations of with and without the / in web.xml <url-pattern> and SimpleForm.html <form action= dont solve the problem  :(